# how to call a variable from array of json in php

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
  vars["price"] = $('#awp_p_impact').val(); //here I will add plus the calculation of the heigh..
        vars["test"] = 100;
        vars["weight"] = $('#awp_p_weight').val();
        vars["quantity"] = $('#quantity_wanted').val();
        vars["quantity_available"] = $('#quantityAvailable').length?$('#quantityAvailable').html():awp_quantity;
        vars["id_product"] = $('#product_page_product_id').val();
        vars["awp_isie"] = ($.browser.msie?"1":"0");
        vars["allow_oos"] = allowBuyWhenOutOfStock?"1":"";

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseDir + 'modules/attributewizardpro/combination_json.php',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        data: vars,
```

how to get/call the vars["test"] in the combinations_json.php ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` give you in PHP when doing it this way?

Comment: I *think* you'd need to do `data: { "vars":vars },` and then access it in PHP with `$vars = $_POST['vars']`.

Comment: Where do you want to get it? In the combination_json.php file? Or do you get some response from that file in the AJAX with the array included?

Comment: @IvoPereira yes in the combination_json.php file but as I can see there are no variables called from the file where the code you see above is. do you think ajax gets the values from the php? its my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are posting your data via Ajax (an object that contain properties), all this stuff will be found in the global var `$_POST` on your PHP script.

You can have access to them with (for example):

```
$test = $_POST['test'];

// $test should contain "100"
```

Comment: thank you this worked, I just need to see one more to get this done because it duplicates the value somewhere in the json.php file but your solution was the answer